# How to add a CustomLayout between two Layouts inside a RelativeLayout programtically?

Tags: android

I have a Relative Layout that has certain elements already defined in the XML.

I have a customLayout that is also defined in the XML. I want to add this customlayout to the mainRelativeLayout programmatically such that it comes between the two views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/verify"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click Me"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5fff43"
        android:layout_below="@+id/verify"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/response"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/error"
        android:background="#34fff5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/response"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I added a view below the verify TextView.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View bannerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testing, rootlayout, false);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) bannerView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.verify);
        rootlayout.addView(bannerView);
```

But the view below the **errorTextView** is still below the **verifyTextView**. I tried to addRule to the verifyTextView like this -

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) error.getLayoutParams();
        lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bannerView.getId());
        error.setLayoutParams(lp2);
```

But nothing has changed. I want to add the customLayout between **verifyTextView** and **errorTextView**

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty LinearLayout between verify button and error TextView. Now you can add view to this LinearLayout programmatically.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5fff43"
    android:layout_below="@+id/verify"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In your code, Simply add the view to this layout:

```
 View bannerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testing, rootlayout, false);
 // option, set layout params to your View
 LayoutParams params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            1f
        );
 bannerView.setLayoutParams(params);
 //add view to layout
 linearlayout.add(bannerView)
```